# Recognising Ubuntu VM hostnames on my local network

Tags: server, 20.04, virtualization, hostname

I suspect this issue may have been answered somewhere already, so please feel free to patiently direct me there (also as I'm new to this community). However I have done A LOT of searching to resolve this and tried various things but not been able to fix it.

I have 2 Ubuntu VM's installed on VirtualBox 6.1 on a Windows 10 Pro desktop. The one VM is Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop (with GUI) and the other VM is Ubuntu 20.04 Server. Hostnames have been configured for both VM's. It is possible to ping both VM's on the Windows command line using the VM IP addresses. The Ubuntu Desktop VM can be pinged using its hostname but the Ubuntu Server cannot be pinged using the hostname.

How can the Ubuntu Server VM be configured so that the hostname is recognised by the Windows host like the Ubuntu Desktop VM?

Comment: Bit late here, but are each of the VMs operating with their network in "Promiscuous mode" with connections set to "Allow all"?

Comment: @Matigo thanks for the response. No, both VM's are not in promiscuous mode, i.e. it is set to 'Deny'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the interesting differences between Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu Desktop is that the Desktop installations will broadcast their existence to the network as `{hostname}.local`, whereas a Server installation will not. Fortunately, this is not too difficult to resolve thanks to `avahi-daemon`.

On your Server VM, do this:

0. Make sure that apt is up to date:

   ```
   $ sudo apt update
   ```
1. Install `avahi-daemon`:

   ```
   $ sudo apt install avahi-daemon
   ```
2. There is no Step 2.

From here your Ubuntu Server VM will broadcast itself on the local network as `{hostname}.local`. You should be able to ping the instance from the VM host so long as the network is configured appropriately.

***Note:** If you would like to have the VM accessible to all machines on your local network, then you will need to change the VM's network settings in VirtualBox to "Bridged" and setting the network device, then setting "Promiscuous Mode" to "Allow All", as in the image below:*

[image: Ubuntu Server VM - Network Config]

Hope this solves your issue